# UITextView contentSize automatically decreases

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UITextView` whose height I am trying to resize as the number of lines increases. Apart form this, I need to resize the `UIView` in which the `UITextView` is contained. I am using the following code for this:

> -(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
>
> ```
> CGFloat before = textView.frame.size.height;
>
> CGRect frame = textView.frame;
>
> frame.size = textView.contentSize;
>
> CGFloat after = frame.size.height, diff = after - before, final = 0;
>
> if (diff>16) {
>     final = 8;
> }else if(diff<-1){
>     final = -16;
> }else{
>     final = 0;
> }
>
> [self.containerView setFrame: CGRectMake(self.containerView.frame.origin.x,
> ```
>
> self.containerView.frame.origin.y-final, self.containerView.frame.size.width,
>   frame.size.height+13)];
>
> ```
> [textView setFrame: frame];
> ```
>
> }

I am also trying to change the Y-position of the container as the text is changed. I am using static number values according to font size to avoid complications.

But the problem is that whenever the `UITextView` enters a new line, it resizes its `contentSize` to the original size and so the frame of the `UITextView` is also reduced for a moment, which looks really ugly. Also, the Y-position depends on this `contentSize` change and it gets all messed up when this automatic resize happens.

I am looking for the same behaviour which apps like whatsapp or viber have. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the containerView includes a textfield and must be drawn around it, regardless of the size of the textfield? If that is, try something like this

```
-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView

{

CGRect frame = textView.frame;

frame.size = textView.contentSize;

//do your magic calculations

[textView setFrame: frame];

[self.containerView setFrame: CGRectMake(self.containerView.frame.origin.x,
self.containerView.frame.origin.y-final, self.containerView.frame.size.width, frame.size.origin.y +frame.size.height+13)];

}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be such a method.